# Does sheer amount affect reaction rates?

Tags: concentration

For example, in the iodine and starch reaction, if I use 20 mL of a set concentration of each, will it be slower to completion if I use 40 mL of each at the same concentration?

Comment: Depends, how you use them.

Comment: In a simple bimolecular reaction between A and B with rate constant k the rate = k[A][B], where [A] is the _concentration_ of A,  and [B] for B, so if the concentration is the same the volume does not matter if other things remain constant, temp , pressure etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you define "completion" by a certain percentage of conversion then no, they will behave exactly the same, provided that things like cooling and stirring are the same in both systems.

Comment: Problem is if you scale up process, those things can't be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here some elements to add to your reflection:

- Some chemicals (among them, many bio-polymers or proteins) can highly change fluid properties (mainly viscosity and surface tension) when dissolved, like you can see when solubizing Starch;
- Sheer stress affects viscosity of [non-Newtonian fluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid) (moderate concentrations of starch are not Newtonian fluids, looks like jelly), and then chemical [advection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection) and [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion). Thus it can affect reaction rate by modifying mass transfer rate;
- Sheer stress may change protein or polymer conformations (think about [Starch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starch) which is a polymer) and then can affect their physical or chemical properties (eg.: it can produce foam a complex polyphasic system, or [denature protein](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1614479/)).
- Dark-purple color you see when mixing Iodine with Starch comes from a very [specific complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex) of [Iodine-Starch chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_test#/media/File:IodineStarch_en.svg);
- Practically, you will apply sheer stress differently to a tank about 1L than 1000L.

Regarding to that aspects, it explains why **sheer stress may impact reaction rates**, in your case: Iodine Starch complex coordination reaction rate.